# Группировка значений

Tags: c#, linq

Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть таблица взаимозаменяемых запчастей, т.е. артикулы запчастей(колонка Article) могут иметь разное значение, но при этом быть взаимозаменяемыми. Они взаимозаменяемы, если у них одинаковое значение CrossGroupId.  Например: Артикул A аналогичен артикулу B, т.к. CrossGroupId у обоих 1. Но в этой таблице есть потерянные связи. 
A аналогичен B - GrossGroupId = 1
B аналогичен С - GrossGroupId = 2
B аналогичен D - GrossGroupId = 3
Здесь три группы, хотя A,B,C,D аналогичны друг другу и должны стоять в одной группе - GrossGroupId = 1.

начальная таблица

| Id | CrossGroupId | Article |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | A |
| 2 | 1 | B |
| 3 | 2 | B |
| 4 | 2 | C |
| 5 | 3 | B |
| 6 | 3 | D |
| 7 | 4 | E |
| 8 | 4 | F |

вот такая таблица должна получится

| Id | CrossGroupId | Article |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | A |
| 2 | 1 | B |
| 3 | 1 | C |
| 4 | 1 | D |
| 5 | 2 | E |
| 6 | 2 | F |

```
                List<ArticleCross> articleCrosses = new() { 
                    new ArticleCross { Id = 1, CrossGroupId = 1, Article = "A" },
                    new ArticleCross { Id = 1, CrossGroupId = 1, Article = "B" },
                    new ArticleCross { Id = 1, CrossGroupId = 2, Article = "B" },
                    new ArticleCross { Id = 1, CrossGroupId = 2, Article = "C" },
                    new ArticleCross { Id = 1, CrossGroupId = 3, Article = "B" },
                    new ArticleCross { Id = 1, CrossGroupId = 3, Article = "D",},
                    new ArticleCross { Id = 1, CrossGroupId = 4, Article = "E",},
                    new ArticleCross { Id = 1, CrossGroupId = 4, Article = "F",},
                    };
```

Думаю, что в цикле каждый раз делать группировку по Article пока не будет повторяющихся значений и менять CrossGroupId на Max из CrossGroupId в группе.
Но  кажется это сложно, буду признателен любой помощи.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Не понял почти ничего.

Comment: Поправьте вопрос, чтоб он объяснял что на что ссылается и по каким правилам. Это иерархия какая-то? Можно пример приближенный к реалиям без такой лютой абстракции?

Comment: Убрал лютую абстрацию) надеюсь, стало понятнее.

Comment: OrderBy(x => x.CrossGroupId)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Выбрать 1 группу
2. Для каждого элемента выбрать группы, в которых он состоит
3. Все найденные группы заменить на изначальную для всех элементов, которые в них есть, если таких замен нет, перейти к п.5
4. Выбрать следующую группу, перейти к п.2, если следующей группы нет, то п.5
5. Сделать Distinct() полученным результатам по Article
6. Переименовать или перенумеровать группы при необходимости.

Попробовал Linq, но скорее всего это можно оптимизировать

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ArticleCross[] items = new[] {
            new ArticleCross { CrossGroupId = 1, Article = "A" },
            new ArticleCross { CrossGroupId = 1, Article = "B" },
            new ArticleCross { CrossGroupId = 2, Article = "B" },
            new ArticleCross { CrossGroupId = 2, Article = "C" },
            new ArticleCross { CrossGroupId = 3, Article = "B" },
            new ArticleCross { CrossGroupId = 3, Article = "D",},
            new ArticleCross { CrossGroupId = 4, Article = "E",},
            new ArticleCross { CrossGroupId = 4, Article = "F",},
        };

        foreach (int group in items.Select(x => x.CrossGroupId).Distinct().ToArray())
        {
            string[] names = items.Where(x => x.CrossGroupId == group).Select(x => x.Article).Distinct().ToArray();
            ArticleCross[] cross = items.Where(x => x.CrossGroupId != group && names.Contains(x.Article)).ToArray();
            int[] aliasGroups = cross.Select(x => x.CrossGroupId).Distinct().ToArray();
            foreach (var item in items.Where(x => aliasGroups.Contains(x.CrossGroupId)))
            {
                item.CrossGroupId = group;
            }
        }

        ArticleCross[] result = items.GroupBy(x => x.Article).Select(g => g.First()).ToArray();

        foreach (var item in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{item.CrossGroupId} {item.Article}");
        }
    }
}

class ArticleCross
{
    public int CrossGroupId { get; set; }
    public string Article { get; set; }
}
```

Вывод в консоль

```
1 A
1 B
1 C
1 D
4 E
4 F
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое, очень признателен. Все работает.